# Is there a nice way in trigger.io to handle OAuth?

Tags: trigger.io

In my case I would have a re-direct URL with a custom url schema like
myapp://oauth

So first I would forward to my oauth login url and then I need to register an event handler for the location change to check if it matches my re-direct url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we have an [example of how to handle oauth2](https://github.com/trigger-corp/forge-template-oauth2)

Using [forge.tabs.openWithOptions](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.2/api/tabs-management.html), you can specify a url to open in a child browser, and a pattern to monitor for to trigger the child browser to close and return the parameters. So you can specify a redirect_url that will match that pattern.

Update: if you want to use Facebook for authentication we've now integrated the native Facebook SDK so you can do authentication with the forge.facebook module:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/facebook.html#modules-facebook

Comment: Oh, I forgot the '*' at the end of the pattern. Now everything works fine. Thanks!