# Is there a nice way in Trigger.io to handle OAuth1.0a for Twitter?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth, trigger.io, kinvey

I'm using [kinvey](http://kinvey.com). They provide this [great tutorial](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/tutorials/how-to-implement-safe-signin-via-oauth) detailing sign-in via oauth. They also handle a considerable amount on their end allowing a very [simple social signin method](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/guides/users#twitter).

The issue is providing a proper Callback URL when creating the app within twitter. How do I make that play nicely with the [tabs:childBrowser](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/tabs.html) in Trigger.IO?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457550/is-there-a-nice-way-in-trigger-io-to-handle-oauth) answer regarding how to use [Trigger.IO to handle OAuth2](https://github.com/trigger-corp/forge-template-oauth2/blob/master/index.html), how would I go about augmenting the method they provide for use with OAuth1.0a for use with Twitter?

Comment: I ran into the same issue and at this time I don't think they have a way to do it like with facebook, I had to do an oAuth service on my server and download the results and save them locally to get the twitter feed in app. The other method would be to use the child browser as stated but its not as clean in my opinion

Comment: @user1717573 have you seen the [this](http://github.com/trigger-corp/forge-template-oauth2)? - it would be great if it could be tweaked somehow.

Comment: @user1717573 [OAuth with modal views](https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/integrations/modal.html) looks helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a demo app which shows how to use `forge.request.ajax` and `forge.tabs.open` to do an OAuth 1.0a flow against Twitter. Might update the docs with the same when a get a second.

https://github.com/goodgravy/forge-spikes/tree/master/twitter-oauth